# Defining Completeness in the Theory of Boolean Algebra

Tags: first-order-logic, boolean-algebra

If one were formalising the theory of Boolean Algebra in first-order logic, would it be possible to define completeness with binary meets and joins, i.e., somehow allowing for infinite meets and joins?

Comment: @LukasKofler That's mixing the algebraic structure of the logic itself with the algebraic structures being described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, this can't be done.**

It certainly can't be done *directly*: the syntax of first-order logic doesn't treat infinite-arity operations, so a complete Boolean algebra thought of as a set $B$ together with a unary function (negation) and two *set-ary* functions (arbitrary meet and arbitrary join) isn't even a first-order structure.

Less trivially, it can't be done *indirectly*, either: there is no set $\Gamma$ of first-order sentences in the language of Boolean algebras which is true in exactly the complete Boolean algebras. The quicket way to see this is via the [downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem): the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$, viewed as a Boolean algebra in the natural way, is complete, but no countable elementary subalgebra of it is complete.

---

Re: the first point above, it's worth noting that we could of course consider an expansion of first-order logic to handle infinite-arity operations. This *(or rather, these - there are multiple ways to implement the idea)* is surprisingly poorly behaved, and even the tamest approaches lack both the compactness and Lowenheim-Skolem properties.

Comment: Thank you, this helps immensely.